# Can I disable IPv6 on AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I edit a SAAS for small businesses. A lot of them don't have a state of the art network configuration, and it creates issues with Cognito.

When trying to login, their web browser makes a POST https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/. Their DNS resolves cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com to an IPv6 (2a05:d018:478:XXXX:443). **But their router does not support IPv6** and the request times out.

A workaround we found is to turn off Internet Protocol Version 6 on their Windows desktops - but it is really edgy.

Do we have any way from the webapp to force the resolution of cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com to an IPv4 ?

Comment: If they're behind a scenario where their network stack is attempting IPv6, but failing, I would think cognito is the least of their issues.  Sites like google should fail in the same manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by AWS support, disabling IPv6 is not possible on Cognito.

However, you can create a CloudFront taking cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com as an origin. On CloudFront, you can choose to [disable IPv6](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig-ipv6enabled) on your distribution.